# Jquery backstretch inside div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, background

I am trying to achive a fullscreen background image inside a div using JQuery.

I am using the [Backstretch plugin](http://srobbin.com/blog/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/), which works fine however it binds the image to the body tag.

I am looking to apply this to a div with the id of home_middle_bg, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the image is binded to a div and that is prepended to the body: you could modify it by hand by replacing (line 69 of the plugin):

```
            if($("body #backstretch").length == 0) {
                $("body").prepend(container);
            }
```

with

```
            if($("#home_middle_bg #backstretch").length == 0) {
                $("body").prepend(container);
            }
```

Comment: Many thanks, Nicola's solution worked great. Thanks for having a look as well Shikiryu.

Comment: Wouldn't you also need to change $("body").prepend(container) to $("#home_middle_bg").prepend(container) ?

Answer (score 2):

I added a new settings option that defaults to body if undefined. So the suggestion from above would look like so:

```
 if($(settings.targetObject + ' #backstretch').length == 0) {
      $(settings.targetObject).append(container);
 }
```

Comment: This pull request has that option added, among others: https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch/pull/93

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use that plugin, you'd need to modify it around here (replace "body" with what you want) : https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch/blob/fcb8ee843b4d88a5081668ec615afd6a57da8242/jquery.backstretch.js#L72

Answer (score 0):

For me the jumping cause in the jquery.backstretch.js plugin was solved by updating the plugin code:

Instead of (default)

```
t.backstretch=function(i,e){return t("body").backstretch(i,e).data("backstretch")}
```

for me it worked when referring backstretch to a different container:

```
t.backstretch=function(i,e){return t("#header").backstretch(i,e).data("backstretch")}....
```

Regards,
ventilator5000